# Adding row values and creating new column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database in which I have to choose three specific stock symbols and find its profit/loss values by subtracting total selling value from total buying value.
[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQTDq.jpg)

My approach- Added 'buy' and 'sell' transaction type separately as a new column named 'nocolumnname' (with minus sign before total sell).
[Total sell and buy values corresponding to its stocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ni0y8.jpg)

My question is that how to again add the total buy and total sell values for 'AMZN', 'CMCSA' and 'FOX' (in alphabetical order) and create a new column named 'profit/loss' in place of 'nocolumnname' column.
Like this:
[Sample_Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZWr2.jpg)

Comment: Please don't include code or data as image. It's hard to use to help you

Answer (score 0):

Normally you'd not create a table, just query something like this:

```
select stock_symbol,sum( 
case when transaction = 'buy'  then amount
case when transaction = 'sell' then -amount
end
) as [profit/loss]
order by stock_symbol
```

or put that in a view (without the `ORDER BY` because neither tables nor views have an order) and select from there

```
select * from the_view where stock_symbol in ('AMZN', 'CMCSA' , 'FOX' ) order by stock_symbol
```

If you really, really want a "table" for some reason like performance, you can create an indexed view, which is basically a table that gets updated as rows are changed in the source tables.

(approximate syntax due to no usable scripts or data)